# SQL Server syntax HAVING COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, `Movie`, `MovieLinkFile` and `File`.

- `Movie` has ID, Tile and other stuff
- `MovieLinkFile` has ID, MovieID and FileID
- `File` has ID, path size and other mediainfo stuff

To find the file path to a movie you would do

```
SELECT m.title, f.path
FROM Movie m, MovieLinkFile mlf, dbo."file" f
WHERE m.ID = mlf.movieId
  AND mlf.fileId = f.id 
  AND m.id = 7777
```

I need to find the movies where there is more than 1 file linked to it.

For instance `movieID = 7777` has in `File`:

```
ID      Path
-------------------------------------------
1244    M:\PathTo\Title 1999\Tile.mp4 
5678    M:\OtherPathTo\Title 1999\Tile.mkv
```

In `MovieLinkFile` there is

```
MovieID   FileID
-----------------
  7777     1234
  7777     5678
```

OR FileID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;

My SQL query isn't working I think because the GROUP by is wrong maybe it needs to be in a sub query?

```
SELECT 
    mlf.movieId, mlf.fileId, f.path 
FROM 
    movielinkfile mlf, "file" f 
WHERE 
    f.path LIKE 'M:\%'
    AND f.id = mlf.fileId
GROUP BY 
    mlf.movieId, mlf.fileId, f.path 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

**Edit:**

Both answers bellow work however they are both returning false positives

I'm only concerned with the movies that have more than 1 file whose path starts with 'M:'  so ignoring any that have two or more files with 1 that start with 'Offline'

Unless there are 3+ files and 2+ start with 'M:'

I amended @GuidoG fiddle
[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b3b2e8da3fd9804cf767dd7f4d538dd)
Movie ID = 111 is returning false because
in MovieFile

(1, 'M:\PathTo\BestFilmEver\BestFilmEver.mkv'),

(2, 'OffLine\BestFilmEver.dvd')
Hope that makes sense

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Learning a valuable lesson. Writing requirements is difficult. Writing code based on requirements that are unclear is difficult. So the point you need to clarify is the relationship between the idea of "more than 2 files" and "start with M". You only want to consider files that start with "M" and the number of those files associated with a movie is greater than 1. Quite frankly I doubt that a file can be shared by multiple movies, making the intersection table (MovieLinkFile) pointless. Consider removing that.

Comment: Using Guido's code, filter the derived table "t" by adding a where clause to the query that is "inside". In short, you must filter before you count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to find the movies with more than one file first, and then join with File

You can try it yourself in [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=08bde1a02674a6599e794ab0b633bb8b)

```
select t.Id as MovieId,
       mf.Path
from   ( select m.Id
         from   Movie m
           inner join MovieLinkFile mlf on m.Id = mlf.MovieId
         group by m.Id
         having count(1) > 1
       ) t
   inner join MovieLinkFile mlf on t.Id = mlf.MovieId
   inner join MovieFile mf on mlf.FileID = mf.Id
```

It basically is doing the same as the answer from @cetin-basoz but with a little different approach. It depends what you find the easiest to read and understand

**EDIT**

Based on the comments I have altered my DBFiddle so it should not return any false positives anymore. I also remove the table Movie as suggested by Cetin.

However, to fully test for false positives I need more sample data, the false positive mentioned in the answer is not visible in the sample data in the question.

[New DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=16ceb6a520b5bae790f1f81c73713a73)

```
select t.Id as MovieId,
       mf.Path
from   ( select mlf.MovieId as Id
         from   MovieLinkFile mlf
           inner join MovieFile mf on mlf.FileID = mf.Id
                                  and  mf.Path like 'M:%'
         group by mlf.MovieId having count(1) > 1
       ) t
   inner join MovieLinkFile mlf on t.Id = mlf.MovieId
   inner join MovieFile mf on mlf.FileID = mf.Id
```

Comment: I think this is better. Probably you don't need Movie table at all since you need the id which is already available in MovieLinkFile: ( select MovieId
         from   MovieLinkFile 
         group by MovieId
         having count(1) > 1 )

Comment: This answer looks easier to read IMH Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

That could be written in a number of ways. One of them is:

```
SELECT mlf.movieId, mlf.fileId, f.path 
FROM movielinkfile mlf
inner join [file] f on f.id = mlf.fileId
inner join (select Movieid, count(*) movies
from Movielink
group by MovieId) ml on mlf.movieId = ml.movieId
where ml.Movies > 1 and f.Path like 'M:\%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT(*) applies to each group.

You are grouping by "mlf.movieId, mlf.fileId, f.path".
Since both the "mlf.fileId" and "f.path" are different for each of the 2 matches, this will create separate groups. So each group will have a COUNT(*) of 1.

If you want to find the movies with multiple files, you need to clean up the groups.

For example

```
SELECT mlf.movieId, COUNT(*) AS number_of_files
FROM   movielinkfile mlf, "file" f
WHERE  f.path LIKE 'M:\%'
AND    f.id = mlf.fileId
GROUP BY mlf.movieId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you need the actual "files" data of such movies, you could go for something like this

```
SELECT ...
FROM Movie m, MovieLinkFile mlf, "file" f
WHERE m.ID = mlf.movieId
AND   mlf.fileId = f.id 
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   movielinkfile mlf2, "files" f2
  WHERE  mlf2.fileId = f2.id
  AND    mlf2.movieId = m.ID
) > 1
```

Comment: Yes I'd need to know  the movie title or at least 1 file path to trace the source